# Are there rewards for delegates who vote or those who delegate them?

Tags: rewards, governance

In the documentation, it is clear how bakers and endorsers are rewarded for their participation in the consensus protocol. The documentation does not mention any rewards for those who participate in the governance process. For example, in Dash, masternodes (nodes that are able to vote) get a reward (45% of the mining reward) for their services in the governance process. Is there a similar thing in Tezos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not. If a baker chooses not to vote on any new proposal, no harm done to themselves; they do not lose rewards. Similarly, voting yay/nay/pass does not gain any additional rewards.

Comment: Got it - thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct incentive to participate in the governance process. Indirect incentives are:

- delegators are likely to move their delegations if their delegates don't vote as the delegators intend (or don't vote at all),
- delegates have tokens locked by the protocol (bonds and frozen rewards) so they have things at stake and want these tokens to remain valuable; this incentivizes them to participate in governance.

There is also [a quite controversial proposition](https://tezos-dev.slack.com/archives/C596FGNUR/p1615312736193300) to penalize delegates that don't vote.